# Why is my query always returning the path of the first image in my table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an index page on which all images uploaded on the database are displayed. When you click a certain image, you're sent to a page that contains all the information about that image. Now I am trying to add a Previous/Next button on that information page that will send you to the Previous/Next image in the database. As you can see first I take the path of the image from the URL, then based on the path I get the Id and then I try to get the path of the previous/next image using the id of the current image. My next image button works, however, my previous button always returns the path of the first image in my database. So clicking next->next->next runs through all my images in the right order, however when I click previous on any image, I get sent to the first image. Any ideas why?

```
<?php

    $realImagePath = $_GET['image'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE path='$realImagePath'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $getResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $currentId = $getResult['id'];

    $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id > $currentId LIMIT 1";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
    $getResult4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4);
    $nextImagePath = $getResult4['path'];

    $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id < $currentId LIMIT 1";
    $result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);
    $getResult5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5);
    $previousImagePath = $getResult5['path'];

    echo "<div class='imageContainer'>"
                    ."<h1>".$getResult['name'].'</h1>'
                    .'<img class="uploadedRealImg" src="uploads/'.$realImagePath .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br><br>"
                    ."<a href='imageInfo.php?image=".$previousImagePath."'>Previous</a>"
                    ."<a href='imageInfo.php?image=".$nextImagePath."'>Next</a><br>"
                    .$getResult['description']."<br><br>"
                    .$getResult['date']."<br><br>"
                    .$getResult['author']."<br><br></div>";
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what value is stored in the "previous" button so that you know whether it's adding the correct value or not?

It also might make more sense to store the path and file name in the table and then just store the id of the previous and next as values in those images. It also might make more sense to do all of this with AJAX rather than refreshing the page each time.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what do you mean by "value is stored in the "previous" button". The previous button sends me to the same page but with different path in the url from which I deduct which image I'm supposed to display. The problem is that the sql5 query always returns the path of the image with id 1.

Comment: It's because you're refreshing the page and starting over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result for `SELECT * FROM image WHERE id < $currentId LIMIT 1` is always going to be the first element in the db. This is your problem. Try this:

`SELECT * FROM image WHERE id < $currentId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Works like a charm! Even though it works nonetheless, do I have to something similar to this about the 'next' query? Also why exactly doesn't my sql work out?

Comment: Yes, it would be best to sort with ASC for the next. MySQL will deliver the result rows based on the order in which entries were made. Often this is fine, but to be sure sort them.

Comment: **Also why exactly doesn't my sql work out? **  It is like asking "give me a number less than 100" - I could answer with the first number that came to mind - not really what you wanted if you were expectng "99". By putting in the DESC order it means "of all the numbers less than 100, sort them into descending order, and then give me the top one".